# 2 array same keys and value check if value from one array is here

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have 2 arrays merge to one array, Now i want to check if value 1 in array `$b` then add special content value to `$b` in foreach.

But in below example added the content to `$s` and `$b`

```
$s = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(1,2,3,4);

 $one = array_merge($s,$b);
 $arr = array_chunk($one, 1);
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
if(in_array($arr[$k][0],$b)){
    echo "c";
}
     echo $arr[$k][0]."<br>";
}
```

Output

```
c1
c2
c3
c4
5
c1
c2
c3
c4
```

And i want that output

```
1
2
3
4
5
c1
c2
c3
c4
```

Comment: can you show expected outcome.

Comment: Why don't you run the `c` add logic on the second array first, then join the two together?

Comment: yes but it's not gonna help cause am using like this <div class="<?php if(in_array($arr[$k][0],$b)){echo "specialclass;"}else{echo "normal;"} ?>"><?php echo $arr[$k][0]; echo "<img src='.$arr[$k][0].' />" ?></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Simple. You just have to check with the **if condition**. If the loop has been repeated more than the length of the array $s, then do echo "c";

```
$s = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(1,2,3,4);

$one = array_merge($s,$b);
$arr = array_chunk($one, 1);
$s_length = count($s);
$i = 1;
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    // Check if the loop has been repeated more than the length of the array $s
    if($i > $s_length){
        echo "c";
    }
    echo $arr[$k][0]."<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if that is what you want but:

```
$s = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(1,2,3,4);

$arr = array_diff($s, $b);

// Search differences between diff() and $s
$cs= "";
$cb= "";
// If array have semantical keys we'll do an array_values()
foreach ( array_values($arr) as $k => $v ){ 
    // If $cs is actually set as 'c'
    if ( "c"!=$cs ){
        // If a value in the diff() array are not in s => $cs = 'c'
        $cs= ( !in_array( $v, $s ,true ))? "c": "";
    }
    // If $cb is actually set as 'c'
    if ( "c"!=$cb ){
        $cb= ( !in_array( $v, $b ,true ))? "c" : "";
    }
}

// Print each array values with associated $c
foreach ( $s as $k => $v ){ 
    echo "<br>$cs$v"    ;
}
foreach ( $b as $k => $v ){ 
    echo "<br>$cb$v"    ;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
c1
c2
c3
c4
```

Comment: this output it's what i need but with my code cause im using array_merge to display 2 array in one foreach and array_chunk to sort the array by each last 3d elements